# ImageView Width inside a stretched table cell

Tags: android, android-layout

I'm createing a TableRow (at runtime) with a different cell count. all coloumns are streched evenly to fill the table and that's fine.
the problem is that inside each cell there is an ImageView that is being streched to the size of the table cell, and I can't manage to set a max width value to that imageview.
here is the code adding the imageview:

```
imgV = new ImageView(getBaseContext());
                imgV.setLayoutParams(new TableRow.LayoutParams(1, TableRow.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT, 1));
                //imgV.setMaxWidth(cellWidth/2);
                imgV.setMaxWidth(maxImgViewWidth);
                //imgV.getLayoutParams().width = maxImgViewWidth ;

                tv.setPadding(5, 0, 5, 30);
                imgV.setBackgroundResource(smiley1Id);
                trIconsRow.addView(imgV);
```

and here is the trIconsRow configuration:

```
<TableLayout
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:stretchColumns="*"
                android:id="@+id/ansTable"
                android:layout_marginTop="10dip"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content">
                <TableRow
                    android:layout_width="match_parent"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:id="@+id/tRowIcons"
                    android:layout_marginBottom="30dip"
                    android:gravity="center"
                    android:layout_gravity="center_horizontal">
                </TableRow></TableLayout>
```

what am I missing here?

Comment: anyone has any idea?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

ok. so what i did was to add a linear layout that would wrap the imageview and will act as a "mediator" between the table cell and the imageview:

```
LinearLayout ll = new LinearLayout(getBaseContext()) ;
                ll.setLayoutParams(new TableRow.LayoutParams(TableRow.LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT,TableRow.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT, 1));
                ll.setGravity(Gravity.CENTER);
                ll.addView(imgV);
                trIconsRow.addView(ll);
```

Answer (score 0):

`android:adjustViewBounds="true"` or with code Call `ImageView#setAdjustViewBounds(boolean).`